# Conditional expectation of a linear transformation of a uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

I don't get how to calculate a conditional expected value. Here's the setting:
$v_s$ and $v_b$ are independent and both uniformly distributed on [0,1]. Furthermore, $p_s(v_s)=a_s +c_sv_s$ and $p_b(v_b)=a_b+c_bv_b$.

Now I am asked to calculate $E[p_s(v_s)|p_s(v_s)≤p_b(v_b)]$ and  $E[p_b(v_b)|p_b(v_b)≥p_s(v_s)]$.

Can anyone please help me?

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: you can simplify this notation drastically by observing that $p_s(v_s)$ and $p_b(v_b)$ are independent uniform $[a_s,a_s+c_s]$ and $[a_b,a_b+c_b]$ respectively. (assuming the $c's$ are greater than 0).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you also help me with the conditional expectation? Unfortunately, I haven't computed conditional expectation yet.

Comment: also, if you don't get how to compute a conditional expected value, this is a horrible problem to start on. Try computing $E(U_1 | U_1 < U_2)$ for $U_1,U_2$ independent $U(0,1)$'s

Comment: The solution states that $E[p_s(v_s)|p_s(v_s)≤p_b(v_b)]=(a_s+p_b)/2$ and $E[p_b(v_b)|p_b(v_b)≥p_s(v_s)]=(p_s+a_b+c_b)/2$ but I don't see how to get there. Could you please explain to me how to get there?

Comment: Posted an answer to the first problem. I would say unless there are additional constraints on the $a$'s and $c$'s, the solution is oversimplified. But if the conditions are there, it matches case 3 in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a uniform random variable $V$ on the interval $[a,b]$ and you want to compute the conditional expected value of $V$ given $V<C,$ where $C$ is a random variable independent of $V$, there are three cases of interest.

First, if $C>b,$ then the inequality $V<C$ gives you no information that you don't already know since you already know $V<b.$ So in that case the conditional expectation is just the regular expectation $(b+a)/2.$

If $C<a,$ then it is impossible that $V<C,$ so the conditional expectation is undefined.

If $a\le C\le b$ then you know that $a < V < C$ so $V$ is conditionally uniform in $[a,C]$ which means that the conditional expected value is $ (a+C)/2.$

So in your original problem, if the constants are picked so that $a_s < p_b < a_s+c_s$ always hold regardless of what $v_b$ is, then the third case gives $E(p_s | p_s < p_b) = (a_s+p_b)/2.$